# How to create an output list which is the sum of alternating elements from an input number_list

Tags: python

I'm trying to sum the even and odd-indexed elements of a list together without the use of the sum() method, but something is going wrong. I'm new to Python so help would be appreciated.

An example would be input `number_list` as [1, 2, 3, 4] then the output list will be [4, 6], which is from the sum of the even-numbered elements 1 and 3, and the odd-numbered elements 2 and 4 from the list `number_list`. Similarly, [5, 8, 3, 2, 6, 7, 1] would have an output list of [8, 10, 9, 9, 5].

This is my code:

```
number_list = [2, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1, 7]

res=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(0, len(number_list)): 
    if(i % 2): 
        res[1] += number_list[i] 
    else : 
        res[0] += number_list[i] 
print("Input List: {0}\n".format(number_list))
print("Output List: {0}\n".format(res))
```

Comment: You can slice, so you can `sum(number_list[::2])` and `sum(number_list[1::2])`.

Comment: this looks like it is working to me...  one tweak:  Your `res` list only needs 2 elements, so initialize it as `res=[0,0]`

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: When writing my answer I did not have the benefit of `Similarly, [5, 8, 3, 2, 6, 7, 1] would have an output list of [8, 10, 9, 9, 5].` which has added confusion.  @GoldenPants I suggest you write the problem in a formal fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you were going for; your first attempt was definitely on target:

```
!/usr/bin/env python3

number_list = [2, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1, 7]

i = 0
r = [0,0]
for n in number_list:
  if (i % 2) == 0:
    # Even
    r[0] += n
  else :
    # Odd
    r[1] += n
  i += 1

print(" Input List: {0}". format(number_list))
print("Output List: {0}". format(r))
```

The result is:

```
 Input List: [2, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1, 7]
Output List: [21, 12]
```

There are some simplifications here, namely throwing out Python nuances and just looking at iterating over a list of numbers, determining whether they are in the even or odd position (the `i` index), and adding (summing) them to the base `r` array.  Is this the most compact and optimized Python code you will encounter? No.  But is it clear as to what you're trying to do - I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer is absolutely correct. However more compact answer would be..

```
r = [0,0]
for n, val in enumerate(number_list):
   j = n % 2
   r[j] += val

print(" Input List: {0}". format(number_list))
print("Output List: {0}". format(r))
```